# $\mathbb{F}_m \cap \mathbb{F}_n = \mathbb{F}_{gcd(m,n)}$

Tags: solution-verification, finite-fields

Let $d=gcd(m,n)$. By the sub-field criterion, $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is a sub-field of both $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, as, $d|n$ and $d|m$.

Thus, $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \cap \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$

*The following is the part I am not confident in.*

Conversly, let $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \cap \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$. Thus $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{F}_{p_m}$, moreover, $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ where $k|m$ and $k|n$.

As $d=gcd(m,n)$ this implies that $k|d$ and hence $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ and thus $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \cap \mathbb{F}_{p^m} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$.

Comment: If you are given in advance some field that contains both $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, then go ahead and write $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \cap \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$.  But, abstractly, different fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are not given as subfields of a large field.

Comment: How do you go from $x \in {\mathbb F}_{p^n}$ and $x \in {\mathbb F}_{p^m}$ to $x \in {\mathbb F}_{p^k}$?

Comment: @Magdiragdag If $x\in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ then $x$ is in a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. The subfield can either be $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ itself, or a smaller field following the subfield criterion.

Comment: So you mean: ${\mathbb F}_{p^n} \cap {\mathbb F}_{p^m}$ is a field; and it must be of the form ${\mathbb F}_{p^k}$ for some $k$; and that $k$ must satisfy $k \mid n$ and $k \mid m$, so $k \mid \gcd(n,m)$. (Note that this all heavily depends on the fact that you can implicitly work in a large field containing all the fields concerned, e.g., the algebraic closure of ${\mathbb F}_p$, and that there is, for every $l \geq 1$, a unique copy of ${\mathbb F}_{p^l}$ in that field. So, I'm assuming that you have established something like that already.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ be an [algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Algebraic_closure).

Since the elements of the subfield $\mathbb F_{p^n}\subset\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ are the roots of $X^{p^n}-X,$ the elements of $\mathbb F_{p^n}\cap\mathbb F_{p^m}$ are the roots of $\gcd(X^{p^n}-X,X^{p^m}-X)=X^{p^d}-X,$ i.e. $\mathbb F_{p^n}\cap\mathbb F_{p^m}=\mathbb F_{p^d}.$